# streaming data between two external computer not on local network

Tags: .net, vb.net, vba, vb6

im trying to stream the computer's screen of home from the computer's screen at work what is the best way to do this ?

```
 listen

 stream
```

basic of sending image

thanks

Comment: Is your intention to reinvent the wheel, or are you just unaware of products like RDP and VNC?

Comment: @SteveDog sorry i have not undestand RDP ==> remote desktop ?? yes remote desktop viewer but with external ip thanks

Comment: I don't see a programming question here.

Comment: Hi, you will need to be quite a bit more specific with your question. you are attempting to replicate an entire software application. If you are interested only in results rather the programming task at hand VNC and several other applications (logmein, gotomypc) can also accomplish this task for you.

Answer (score 1):

RDP (remote desktop) and VNC can both connect to any IP address.  It does not have to be a "local" IP address.  The question is not whether or not they CAN do it, the question is whether or not your IP address is publicly accessible on the necessary port.  This is a matter of properly setting up your IP routing on the network.  However, quite often you don't want to expose those ports to the internet, so often VPN's are used to establish a secure network over the internet.  Hamachi is a popular free and simple VPN product. If you don't want to go through the trouble of setting up a VPN, there are many other products out there that don't require anything more than a mere internet connection on both ends (e.g. logmein, gotomypc, etc.), however, these require going through their third-party servers for the connection.

Comment: thanks for this answer , yes but what about logmein gotomypc how they work ???? and what about P2P i can't apply this with p2p ?

Comment: What's this to do with .Net/vb.Net/Vba/VB6 ? Instead of a programming question, you are now asking how two completely different technologies (gotomypc and P2P) work. This is waaaaaay out of scope, mate.

Comment: What do you mean by P2P?